# Bayesian inference for simple gaussian model with measurement error

Tags: bayesian, measurement-error

I'm having trouble understanding how to specify a model for Bayesian inference.

I have a set of measurements, each with known uncertainty, and I would like to infer the mean of the measurements with gaussian model. The mean is known to be within the interval `[0,1]`, so I use an appropriate prior to enforce that. But I'm not sure that I'm handling the measurement uncertainty properly.

The model I have is
$$
\begin{align}
x_{\textrm{obs},i} &\sim \textrm{Normal}(x_{\textrm{true},i}, \sigma_{\textrm{true},i}) \\
x_{\textrm{true},i} &\sim \textrm{Normal}(\mu, \sigma) \\
\mu &\sim \textrm{Uniform}(0, 1) \\
\sigma &\sim \textrm{Exponential}(0.25)
\end{align}
$$
where the "obs" variables are the known values and uncertainties for my measurements.

Is this correct?

Comment: Do you have _repeated_ measurements, i.e. multiple $x_{\mathrm{obs},i}$ for each $i$?

Comment: I have known, normally distributed error for each point